# Using Numba with scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, numba

Has anyone succeeded in speeding up scikit-learn models using numba and jit compilaition. The specific models I am looking at are regression models such as Logistic Regressions.

I am able to use numba to optimize the functions I write using sklearn models, but the model functions themselves are not affected by this and are not optimized, thus not providing a notable increase in speed. Is there are way to optimize the sklearn functions?

Any info about this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scikit-learn makes heavy use of numpy, most of which is written in C and already compiled (hence not eligible for JIT optimization).

Further, the LogisticRegression model is essentially LinearSVC with the appropriate loss function. I could be slightly wrong about that, but in any case, it uses LIBLINEAR to do the solving, which is again a compiled C library.

The makers of scikit-learn also make heavy use of one of the python-to-compiled systems, Pyrex I think, which again results in optimized machine compiled code ineligible for JIT compilation.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. What can one use as alternative then? tensorflow?

Comment: In general, the scikit-learn models are very performant on multi-core systems. If you require the usage of GPUs to meet your performance, then yes, you must switch to something like TensorFlow and utilize GPU-optimized algorithms.

Comment: The answer implies numba does not optimize numpy-heavy code which is not true.

Comment: I agree with @Keto. The docs say "numba [...] works best on code that uses NumPy arrays and functions, and loops."

Answer (score 1):

The `@numba.vectorize` for arrays and `@numba.guvectorise` for matricies, are decorators may help since they work to combine loop operations. They generate so called "ufunc"s which achieve this goal, but instead of having to manually write the c code yourself it generates it from the python input.

See: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html